# c# how to best put array or list into class that also has name?

Tags: c#, class, oop, jagged-arrays

Instead of doing my old non OOP way I am trying to do what people claim is best. I need to store about 9 different Int arrays of differing lengths. I also need to associate them with a String Name "this is called etc.." I was thinking it would make sense to store that all into a class object so I can cleanly iterate through them later on without looking to two different places using the same for loop iterator.

Example:

```
public class Thing
{
    public List<int> SDNA {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}   
}

List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>
    {
        new Thing { SDNA = {2,4,5,7,9,11},Name = "First Thing"}
     }
```

I get a null ref exception (I am assuming its cause of the list within a class somehow) I tried creating a list this way to clear the null ref but it had some other errors.

```
List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
things.Add(new Thing() {SDNA = {2,4,5,7,9,11},Name = "The first things name"});
```

Errors of invalid token etc. Should I just do it with two different stored arrays, one for names and a jagged array for the Ints and then reference them each? That feels ugly to me. Why can't I store them all into one thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `Dictionary<string, int[]>`? Where `Key` is for *name* and *value* is for `int[]` arrays.

Comment: First code: you need to initialize, you can do that direct in the declaration. Second code: `SDNA` is a `List<int>` not an `int`

Comment: @Charlieface I fixed code typo on here. It was as list<int> earlier but typo in translation to this website

Comment: Second code should work now. What is the error?

Comment: @Charlieface  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration. Type expected. ) expected. Tuple must contain at least two elements. There are like 20 errors lol

Comment: @DmitryBychenko
That could work, so would it be better to put it into a class then how do you reference it within there? Or should I just not use a class for it? I am not getting the point of classes when I can do the same things not using them. maybe?

Comment: Are you using `new {...` or `new Thing() {...`?

Comment: @Charlieface the Thing one. I tested with just new now and same errors.

Comment: No no you need to specify the type `new Thing() {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *simplest case* if you want just to have name to value (array) association, you can try using a simple `Dictionary`, e.g.

```
 private Dictionary<string, List<int>> things = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() {
   {"First thing", new List<int>() {2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11}},
 };
```

then you can use it

```
 // Add new thing
 things.Add("Some other thing", new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

 // Try get thing
 if (things.TryGetValue("First thing", out var list)) {
   // "First thing" exists, list is corresponding value
 }
 else {
   // "First thing" doesn't found
 }

 // Remove "Some other thing"
 things.Remove("Some other thing");

 // Iterate over all {Key, Value} pairs (let's print them):
 foreach (var pair in things)
   Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} :: [{string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}]");
```

However, if `Thing` is not just `SDNA + Name` combination (more properties, methods are expected) I suggest

```
 private Dictionary<string, Thing> things
```

declaration

Comment: So no class needed it seems to just use the dictionary as one. That makes sense to me. How do you iterate through values of the strings and individual values inside each list? Syntax is confusing to me here because there is nothing to reference like an array index number. Or would it look like multi dim or jagged?

Comment: @user10304: in order *titerate* you can use `foreach` loop (see my edit)

Comment: pair.Value[1]  is what I was looking for in that, thanks! Works

Comment: @user10304: in case of *dictionary* you can put `var list = things["First thing"];` and get value by *key* (which is name here) not by index

Comment: I have to check numerical index within the array for the program though. It works I just put pair.Value[index to check] this was sort of complex I guess with the array nested inside the dictionary which is a sort of an array object too. This is good to know. Thanks Dmitry! Awesome to learn something new after so many years